# Is the book "A Course of Modern Analysis" still relavent?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

The book [A Course of Modern Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521588073) by G. N. Watson, E. T. Whittaker is probably old enough to have it's copyright expired.

Is the contents and structure of the book still relevant to worth revising or are there better books or approaches of what that book contains that book is no longer relevant in it's subject topic?

Are there any other more modern books in the same subject matter?

Comment: It's still a great book. It is my preferred introduction to studying special functions [which is a big focus of the book, and perhaps why it fell in popularity]. My PhD advisor learned from this book in the 1970s, and I eventually found that it helped me get a foot up with special functions as well. Are there equivalent books? Probably. And there might even be better books. But this book is certainly good enough as an introduction.

Comment: @mixedmath : do you think it is worth to be Latexified? or better to modified and revised, I too like that book just don't know if spending the time to Ltexify it would be justified.

Comment: It's said that it was Lars Onsager's favorite text, and he had it intensely dog-eared and had done every problem. To me, that alone makes it worth reading today. But, in more direct answer to your question, yes, the contents are still relevant and not really in need of much of an update. There are plenty of other, newer treatments of special functions out there (and no doubt many of them are better in some aspect), but I doubt if Whittaker and Watson read them, they would learn anything new.

Comment: For what it's worth: The book is in the public domain. As of December 26, 2016, no one had applied for a copyright clearance to product this book for Project Gutenberg. Referring to the [1902 edition](https://archive.org/details/acoursemodernan00watsgoog) at the Internet Archive, I estimate that LaTeXifying this book from the OCR text represents about 120-200 hours' work, depending on one's typing speed, facility with LaTeX and book-length manuscripts, and the quality of the final product.

Comment: Why latex it ? What is the advantage ? There are readable scans available.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus because it looks nicer! It is a lovely book, it deserves the best typesetting.